# Is the default rule vue/attribute-hyphenation in conflict with vue/prop-name-casing?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, eslint, eslint-plugin-vue

I am working on the project using eslint-plugin-vue and I have child and parent components.
the child component needs to pass a value into parent components.

```
// parent
export default {
  name: 'recordDetail',
  props: {
     'record-id': { // however this will violate vue/prop-name-casing
        type: Number
     }
  }
}
```

```
<!-- child -->
<recordDetail
  :record-id="123"> <!-- it will violate vue/attribute-hyphenation if this is recordId="123" -->
</recordDetail>
```

Please give me advice on how you will deal with this and what is the best practice on Vue.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `kebab-case` in templates and `camelCase` on the JS side.

```html
<recordDetail :record-id="123" />
```

will correspond to

```js
props: {
  recordId: {
  ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I would also add that according to general rules it should be `<record-detail/>`

Comment: @MichałSadowski good point, I missed the component name in the tag - but actually I think the best practice is to use `PascalCase` for component tags in SFCs and string templates, but `kebab-case` when using the DOM as template, if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: You're indeed right, also checked that I've been thinking about the guideline for nuxt components. It's all confusing.

Comment: Actually, `using kebab-case everywhere is also acceptable`, according to the docs so it's always safer to use kebab-case.